# React Native: How to change inputfield to selected item

Tags: react-native

So what I'm trying to do is fetching data from an API (works well), that has this autocomplete function.
Link to example: https://autocomplete.aws.dk/
Link to the guide: https://autocomplete.aws.dk/guide2.html

What is hard for me, is that the guide is HTML, and this is suppose to work in React Native.

So far I made an input field, that can detect when writing minimum two letters will show a list of addresses.

What I want is when the address is clicked, it takes that value and places it in the input field.

Heres my code:

The API fetch:

```
import React from "react";
import url from "./url";

export default class DawaFetch extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
  options: {},
  minCharacters: 2,
  };

  state = {
  value: "",
  suggestions: [],
  };

 handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
 this.setState({ value });
  if (this.props.minCharacters <= value.length) this._fetch(value);
  };

_fetch = (value) => {
fetch(
  url("https://dawa.aws.dk/adresser/autocomplete", {
    q: value,
    ["per_side"]: 100,
    ...this.props.options,
  }),
  {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    },
  }
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => this.setState({ suggestions: json }))
  .catch((err) => console.error("parsing failed", err));
};

render = () =>
 this.props.children({ ...this.state, handleChange: this.handleChange });
}
```

And here is my view:

```
          <DawaFetch>
            {({ value, suggestions, handleChange }) => {
              console.log(suggestions);
              return (
                <View>
                  <CustomInputs
                    type="text"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />

                  {suggestions.map((suggestion) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                    <NormalText key={suggestion.adresse.id}>{suggestion.tekst}</NormalText>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  ))}

                </View>
              );
            }}
          </DawaFetch>
```

Tried different solutions by making it a FlatList with renderItem, and making an onPress function, but I could never make it work.

Hopefully someone can guide me in the right direction, I might been overthinking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`React-Native TextInput onChange value is not available inside the target as it's available in HTML`, `Remove target` from `handleChange` function like below, also it's not onChange it's onChangeText in TextInput.

```
handleChange = (value) => {
this.setState({ value });
if (this.props.minCharacters <= value.length) this._fetch(value);
};
```

You can achieve your desired functionality in a very simple manner.
Add this to your `DawaFetch` class.

```
OnItemSelection=(address)=>{
this.setState({value: address})
}
```

Add this to your render Function

```
render = () =>
  this.props.children({ ...this.state, handleChange: this.handleChange, OnItemSelection: this.OnItemSelection });
```

}

Then make these changes in your `DawaFetch` component

```
<DawaFetch>
        {({ value, suggestions, handleChange, OnItemSelection }) => {
          console.log(suggestions);
          return (
            <View>
              <CustomInputs
                type="text"
                value={value}
                onChangeText={handleChange}
              />

              {suggestions.map((suggestion) => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> OnItemSelection(suggestion.adresse)}>
                <NormalText key={suggestion.adresse.id}>{suggestion.tekst}</NormalText>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ))}

            </View>
          );
        }}
      </DawaFetch>
```

`Edit:`Here is Snack having solution

https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/bad-raisins

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made the changes you suggested, but I keep getting an error in my DawaFetch component, that OnItemSelection is not a function. Literally copy pasted it. It is also displaying with the color of a function and everything.

Comment: Can you please confirm me `OnItemSelection ` function is available in your `DawaFetch` component?

Comment: have you added `OnItemSelection` in your `Dawafetch` class?

Comment: I've added it to the `DawaFetch` component, next to the `handleChange` - And then using it on the onPress.
The `OnItemSelection` function is implented underneath the `handleChange` function in the `DawaFetch` class. I have looked it through many times now, too make sure I didn't do some rookie mistake, to take your time on this problem.

Comment: Can you send me the whole file? or can you share a snack?

Comment: I've tried to recreate it here: https://snack.expo.io/xmsPPd4EY

Comment: In the above snack, the  suggestions array is empty so I can't check any of the items

Comment: I've been sitting with this for a while now, but heres one where the suggestions are comming through: https://snack.expo.io/bXJQJZMvL. I have made it work somehow now. But if I remove the target as you suggested at first, it will try to place an object before its clicked. If I keep it, it seems to work. My only problem now is, its expecting a string so I get [object Object].

Comment: Snack is been the same as it was the previous time, nothing appearing on the screen and suggestion array is empty.

Comment: Its har to see. But there is an almost invisible input field showing. When hovering your mouse on it, you'll see it (it's at the top). Then for an example write "da", then you can see it comes out with some danish addresses.

Comment: I have fixed your problem related to [Object, Object] but the suggestion remains empty while making search

Comment: Cool! Can you just share the solution back to me  regarding the [object Object]. I have no clue how you can't see the suggestions, but your answers has led me to a fix. Thanks!!

Comment: here you go, All of the problems is been fixed here.
https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/7ddf0f
Object, Object and when you make a search select some value in the list it will be shown in the textInput.

Comment: It has, works like a charm. Upvoted (because I have less than 15, it wont show, but you got it) and marked as solved based on your solution.